# Bootstrap: height = span width / make a square based on .span2 width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to make a div the height of a ".span2" (basically a square) which also works responsive. Like this:

```
<div class="span2 square>Hello</div>
.span {height: @span2;}
```

But i cant find a working less-variable / class or something similar in bootstrap. Can you help?

Best
68bydesign

Comment: first of all, is span2 dynamic? you need to declare a static height for span2 for it to work, else you have to resort to JS

Comment: LESS, is a preprocessors, it create a static CSS upon compile, it's not design to work like how you wanted.

Comment: You could try to do something with [vw](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) unit (works with responsive, but it's more difficult), or simply use JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

My understanding is that `.span2` has this.

```
.span2 {
    width:14.364640883%;
}
```

That being the case, the closest, absent a JS solution, is viewport units.

NOTE: This isn't an **exact** square but I think you'd be hard pressed to spot the difference.

```css
.span2 {
  width: 14.364640883%;
}
.span2.square {
  height: 14.364640883vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="span2 square"></div>
```